# Ionic 4 ion-skeleton inside ion-item is not filling the item space

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to use `ion-skeleton` inside an `ion-item`. Instead of having the skeleton text filling the whole ion-item space, it is compressed in a few pixels space.

I noted that the skeleton text container (`ion-text`) is not stretching without any text inside.

I've also tried the following without success:
- use a div instead of an ion text
- remove h1 and p
- use any combination of [Flex Properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#flex-properties) as `.ion-align-items-stretch` and `.ion-align-items-stretch`

Here is the structure of my item:

```
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding" lines="full" detail="true" *ngFor="let num of [0,1,2,3,4,5]">
  <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
    <ion-skeleton-text animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text>
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <ion-text>
    <h1><ion-skeleton-text animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text></h1>
    <p><ion-skeleton-text animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text></p>
    <p><ion-skeleton-text animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text></p>
    <p><ion-skeleton-text animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text></p>
  </ion-text>
</ion-item>
```

and here what I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance,
kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, the idea has been triggered while answering to an answer.

It was as simple as that: just add the following to the scss sheet of the page:

```
ion-text {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Beautiful perfect skeleton screen in Ionic**

**HTML code**

```
<ion-list lines="none" *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3]">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-skeleton-text width="40%" class="animate-skeleton-background"></ion-skeleton-text>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-skeleton-text width="60%" class="animate-skeleton-background"></ion-skeleton-text>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-skeleton-text width="100%" class="animate-skeleton-background"></ion-skeleton-text>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**CSS code**

```
.animate-skeleton-background {
 height:20px;
 -webkit-animation: infinite bgcolorchange 2s;
 animation: 2s infinite bgcolorchange;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

@keyframes bgcolorchange {
0% {
color: #f2f2f2;
}
25% {
background: lightgray;
}
50% {
background: #f2f2f2;
}
75% {
background: lightgray;
}
100% {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgcolorchange {
0% {
background: #f2f2f2;
}
25% {
background: lightgray;
}
50% {
background: #f2f2f2;
}
75% {
background: lightgray;
}
100% {
background: #f2f2f2;
}
}
```